# Querying a MySQL database with Python without installing MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'd like to query a MySQL database using Python, but evidently the MySQLdb package requires a huge toolchain of MySQL stuff to be separately installed.

How can I query a MySQL database using a Python script without installing a bunch of unnecessary MySQL stuff, including conferring MySQL server capability on the client machine?

I don't love Perl, but it appears that the DBI package allows a Perl script to interface with MySQL without any MySQL stuff external to the package. I'm looking for something similar for Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find a pure mysql python library.  I have seen a couple over the last couple months.  A quick google search yoelded pymysql.  It has a large following on github.  It looks promising. Pymysql is a pure python mysql client.
https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb is just one of the available database drivers. It requires all that extra installation stuff, because it compiles c extensions and is one of the faster options.

There are a handful of other database drivers, some of which are pure-python.

The SqlAlchemy project has one of the more up-to-date collections of database drivers:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

PyMysql is a pure python driver, so it won't need to be built against the local MySql library.